# How to order by random in SQL with Google Sheets?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have to use the query language SQL to select a result in a Google sheet.

I would like to order by random but I don't find a working function.

I use this:

```
Select E limit 3 sort by random()
```

Doc:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: I can't find `Random()` in that documentation. Are you sure querylanguange supports it?

Comment: You’re right I dont’f find it. So I wonder how to do that.

Comment: I don't know, I've never worked with this queryLanguage. It's a lot like SQL but I'm guessing it still has some things different. Perhaps someone else can help more than me.

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(#DATA_RANGE,CONCATENATE("SELECT A LIMIT 1 OFFSET ", RANDBETWEEN(0,COUNTA(#COLUMN_RANGE)-1)),-1)
```

Fill in `#DATA_RANGE` and `#COLUMN_RANGE` as needed.

For example:

```
=QUERY(A2:B8,CONCATENATE("SELECT A LIMIT 1 OFFSET ", RANDBETWEEN(0,COUNTA(A2:A8)-1)),-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions I've found:

First, Add a column that just contains =RAND() to your dataset.
Second, Include and order by the column in your QUERY. No need to actually select or display the random number.

e.g. =query(A:B, 'select A order by B') assuming A is your dataset and B =RAND();

Alternatively you can append a set of random numbers to your dataset programmatically. It's just a nuisance that combining arrays like that renames your columns to COLX, where X is the order of the columns from the more legible A/B/C/Whatever.

e.g. =query({A:A, RANDARRAY(ROWS(A:A))}, 'select COL1 order by COL2')

A third way that might work is to add an =SORT(A:A, RANDARRAY(ROWS('Using Sort Part A'!A2:A), 1), TRUE). One problem with this solution though is that it generates a random number of EVERY column, whether or not it's filled out and includes it in our dataset. You could probably get around this with clever use of FILTER and ISTEXT.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A:A), 99^99), A:E}, 
 "select Col6 where Col6 is not null order by Col1 limit 3", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Ok but the result of the select will be all time the same. I’d’like To have a random answer to each query

Comment: Shouldn't you use ROWS and now ROW? ROW(A:A) always returns 1. ROWS(A:A) is actually your row count.

Also why 99^99? Wouldn't it be better to RANDBETWEEN(0, ROWS(A:A))?

Comment: @JeffreyVanAlstine yes, standalone =ROW(A:A) will output 1 but combined with =ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A)) will output every row out there. 99^99 was used just because its shorter than ROWS(A:A) ...the answer was posted long time ago. nowdays I would answer it with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ifK.png